# Styling a custom React styled-component in Typescript?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have this `CustomScroll` component.

**CustomScroll.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface Container_DIV {
  className: string
}

const Container_DIV = styled.div<Container_DIV>`
  // SOME CCS PROPERTIES
`;

interface CustomScroll {
  className: string
}

const CustomScroll: React.FC<CustomScroll> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering CustomScroll...");

  return(
    <Container_DIV className={props.className}>
      {props.children}
    </Container_DIV>
  );
};

export default React.memo(CustomScroll);
```

Note that I'm passing the `className` props to let `styled-components` do its thing.

And when I consume it I need to style it with some extra properties.

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import CustomScroll from "./Parts/CustomScroll";

const Filters_DIV = styled(CustomScroll)`
  // SOME CCS PROPERTIES
`;
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<CustomScroll, "className"> & Partial<Pick<CustomScroll, never>>, "className"> & { theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
>
> Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<CustomScroll, "className"> & Partial<Pick<CustomScroll, never>>, "className"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
>
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<NamedExoticComponent, DefaultTheme, {}, never>): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
>
> Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<CustomScroll, "className"> & Partial<Pick<CustomScroll, never>>, "className"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.ts(2769)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of what was wrong, but it seems that you need to spread more than the `className` prop.

So I've decided to spread the full `{...props}` object into the `CustomScroll` component.

**NOTE:** If anyone could explain what was wrong, and why is the full `props` necessary, I'm very interested in knowing that.

This is now working:

**CustomScroll.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface Container_DIV {}  // THIS INTERFACE IS NOT BEING USED

const Container_DIV = styled.div<Container_DIV>`
  // SOME CCS PROPERTIES
`;

interface CustomScroll {}   // THIS INTERFACE IS NOT BEING USED

const CustomScroll: React.FC<CustomScroll> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering CustomScroll...");

  return(
    <Container_DIV {...props}>   {/* ALL PROPS ARE BEING SPREADED */}
      {props.children}
    </Container_DIV>
  );
};

export default React.memo(CustomScroll);
```

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import CustomScroll from "./Parts/CustomScroll";

const Filters_DIV = styled(CustomScroll)`
  // SOME CCS PROPERTIES
`;
```